# Use docker compose to connect API to database

Tags: docker

I have the below docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  server:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: grpc-server
    hostname: grpc-server
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres-db
    hostname: postgres
    networks:
      - mynet
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

However my server container logs are indicating it can't connect to the db.

```
[error] failed to initialize database, got error dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
```

I'm assuming I need to inject the `db` path into the `server` somehow via the `mynet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your grpc-server container tries to connect to the database using the address `127.0.0.1:5432`.

By default, docker compose creates a virtual network where each container is addressed using it's service name. However, you've overridden that by specifying `hostname: postgres` for your database container.

So your grpc-server needs to connect to the database using the address `postgres:5432` rather than `127.0.0.1:5432`.

Comment: Awesome! I just wasn't sure of the convention. So I would set an environment var for the server using postgres:5432 then from the code read it in instead.